# What's wrong with the command hadoop dfs -mkdir -p /user/flume/tweets/

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

Trying to create  directory to store tweeter data. While giving this command it says:

```
mkdir: `–p': No such file or directory
mkdir: `/user/flume1/tweets/': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like a typo: you seem to have typed `–p` instead of `-p`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> hadoop dfs

use

> hadoop fs

and you will be able to create the directory as hadoop dfs is deprecated. I have attached a screenshot for your reference

[image: Please click on the link to view full image].

Comment: Yes, @cricket_007 you are right and I have only suggested to use that command instead of that as it seems that there is nothing wrong in the command posted by Sudeep.

Comment: `-p` is different from `–p`

Comment: Look at the title of the question. He has used the right one.

Comment: The title was typed manually. The command itself probably was copied. Plus, the question itself doesn't show the actual command ran